# Рисование фигур на элементе wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Всем доброе время суток! Можно ли реализовать отрисовку различных фигур на каком-то элементе управления, для примера этот:
 `<lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1" VisualElements="{Binding Visuals}" Name="chart" />`
Данный элемент это LiveChart. Можно ли на примере прямоугольника показать, как можно реализовать отрисовку фигур? На обычной win forme все спокойно получалось из-за события paint, но как я понял в wpf его нет.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `<lvc:CartesianChart />` уже, судя по всему, и так лежит в `Grid`'е. Чтобы нарисовать что-то поверх, просто положите это что-то в ту же ячейку `Grid`'а.

Например:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1" VisualElements="{Binding Visuals}" Name="chart" /> 
    <Path Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="1"
          Data="M 0,3 L 7,0 L 5,7 z" Stroke="DarkCyan" Fill="LightGray"/>
</Grid>
```

Фигуры отрисуются сами, никакой `OnPaint` вам не нужен.

Comment: перед о мной стоит следующая задача, на элементе `<lvc:CartesianChart />` рисовать различные фигуры, затем отслеживать, чтобы при построении точечных графиков точки не попадали в интервала нахождения фигур. Плюс надо еще иметь полный контроль над этими фигурами(т.е. удалять их и перемещать). Все это это реализовал на обычной вин форме. Но вот как пересел на wpf столкнулся с проблемой и никак не получается не то что управлять фигурами, а вообще их рисовать. Можете подсказать пожалуйста как начать рисовать эти фигуры? используя тот же элемент `Path`

Comment: @АлександрМустафин: А что вас не устраивает в этом коде? Вы ж рисуете элементом `Path` поверх вашего `chart`'а.

Comment: да вроде все устраивает в этом элементе) просто как с его помощью реализовать рисование мышкой в этом загвоздка заключается, плюс таких объектов может быть много

Comment: Ах, у вас не рисование кодом, а рисование **мышкой**! Это совсем другая история. Вкратце, нужно подписаться на мышиные события и добавлять узлы в `Path`. А что, в WinForms можно было «рисование мышкой» сделать автоматически? В любом случае, имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос про это.

Comment: я создал новую тему этому вопросу. Автоматически конечно нельзя в вин форме рисовать мышкой) там как-то проще все делалось. может быть конечно и с использованием wpf просто, еще не до конца въехал в это. А как создавать узлы в Path? и в какой момент вообще происходит рисование, раз нет свойства Paint, обычно в нем происходило отображение фигуры, а всякие mouse up и mouse down служили для отслеживания координат фигур

Comment: @АлександрМустафин: А в WPF вы вообще никогда не должны задумываться о том, когда происходит рисование. Вы добавляете визуальный объект (например, Path) в окно — и оно отрисуется вскоре. Вам не нужно думать, когда именно.

Comment: можете пожалуйста показать какой-нибудь легкий пример отрисовки фигуры мышкой на примере Path

Comment: @АлександрМустафин: Сейчас напишу в вопросе, подождите :)

Comment: @АлександрМустафин: Написал.